# LESS - how to parse/escape parametric variables (ie. variable variables) in a mixin/loop

Tags: css, variables, less, mixins

I'm attempting to loop through a number of indexed variables, in this case colours, to create a class for each. Something along the lines of this:

```
@colour-1: #FF0000;
@colour-name-1: "red";

.loop (@index) when (@index > 0) {
  @colour: ~"@{colour-@{index}}";
  @name: "@{colour-name-@{index}}";

  (~'*[data-colour="@{name}"]') {
    background-color: @colour;
    background-color: hsla(hue(@colour), saturation(@colour), lightness(@colour), 0.5);
  }

  .loop(@index - 1);
}
.loop (0) {}
.loop (1);
```

Rather than providing a fallback variable for IE<9, I'd like to update each colour/value programatically within the mixin to provide both an RGBA & Hex version. Problem is the @{@var} doesn't evaluate until after the fact and so won't parse as a colour.

Is there a way to escape the variables so they don't pass by reference?
JSFiddle here showing the output: http://jsfiddle.net/Qj2cZ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On further examination (and following a bit of a breather) I found a working solution for  less v1.3.3. If you are using v1.4 I would still recommend ScottS's answer, as this hacks around a bug.

As mentioned, the issue is with the variable not being parsed in time for the color() function. However if the variable is evaluated in one function and passed to another for conversion to a colour everything works fine. So the following outputs the required styles:

```
@colour-1: #FF0000;
@colour-name-1: "red";

.loop (@index) when (@index > 0) {
  @colour: ~"@{colour-@{index}}";
  @name: "@{colour-name-@{index}}";
  .setColour(@colour, @name);
  .loop(@index - 1);
}

.setColour (@colour-string, @name) {
  @colour: color(@colour-string);
  (~'*[data-colour="@{name}"]') {
    background-color: @colour;
    background-color: hsla(hue(@colour), saturation(@colour), lightness(@colour), 0.5);
  }
}

.loop (0) {}
.loop (1);
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/LJ3zX/

Answer (score 3):

The multiple reference to the variable is definitely causing issues with the color functions. This may be a bug. I have not come up with a solution for LESS 1.3.3 or lower.

However, I did come up with a working solution in the latest (currently beta) version (1.4) of LESS by building two larger "array" type variables, `@colours` and `@colour-names` to put all the individually defined color variables into. Then we use the new `extract()` function to access those in the loop, and you can get what you desire. Whether 1.4 is an option for you or not at this time you will have to determine.

### LESS 1.4 Working

**LESS Code**

```
@num-colours: 3;

@colour-1: #FF0000;
@colour-name-1: "red";
@colour-2: #00FF00;
@colour-name-2: "green";
@colour-3: #0000FF;
@colour-name-3: "blue";

@colours: @colour-1 @colour-2 @colour-3;
@colour-names: @colour-name-1 @colour-name-2 @colour-name-3;

.define-colours-loop (@index) when (@index =< @num-colours) {
  @colour: extract(@colours, @index);
  @name: extract(@colour-names, @index);

  *[data-colour="@{name}"] {
    background-color: @colour;
    background-color: hsla(hue(@colour), saturation(@colour), lightness(@colour), 0.5);
  }

  .define-colours-loop((@index + 1));
}
.define-colours-loop (0) {}
.define-colours-loop (1);
```

**CSS Output**

```
*[data-colour="red"] {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
*[data-colour="green"] {
  background-color: #00ff00;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
*[data-colour="blue"] {
  background-color: #0000ff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: thanks Scott, looks good. It's a production site but pre-compiled so the beta version should be cool.  Will get a chance to try it tomorrow and accept the answer. cheers!